# Truth table confusion

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, boolean-algebra

I'm given a conditional statement

> $ ~p \lor q \rightarrow r$

From what I understand, the state of $r$ is dependent on the state of $p$ and $q$. The truth table I came up with based on this is:

\begin{array}{ccc}
p&q & r \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 1\\
\end{array}

However, I used a truth table generator to check my answer, and I'm getting confusing results.

\begin{array}{ccc|c}
p&q & r & \lnot p\lor q \to r\\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 &0\\
0 & 0 & 1 &1\\
0 & 1 & 0& 0\\
0 & 1 & 1& 1\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 0& 0\\
1 & 1 & 1& 1\\
\end{array}

I fail to understand how $r$ can have different states despite $p$ and $q$ remaining the same, if its conditionally dependent on them. I also don't understand where the constants on the rightmost column are being derived from. Wouldn't they be the same as $r$?

Am I just using the online truth table tools wrong?

Comment: And what is the question you've been asked?

Comment: @amrsa To write a truth table for the conditional statement "~p ∨ q -> r"

Comment: That's not what you did. The answer to that is the other link, of the online generator. Your table tells whether or not $r$ should be true, as a function of the truth value of $p$ and $q$. The other shows when is the implication true.

Comment: This might be a case of missing parentheses.  Is the formula $(\lnot p \lor q)\rightarrow r$, or is it $(\lnot p) \lor (q\rightarrow r)$ ??

Comment: "I fail to understand how r can have different states despite p and q remaining the same"  Because $r$ isnt a *result* of s and q.  r is a third independent variable.  The question isn't evaluate the truth of (Jack is not a bird) OR (mike is a horse).  The question is evaluate the truth of IF [(Jack is not a bird) OR (mike is a horse) THEN (Paul is an elephant)].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The “$\to$” in $\sim p\lor q\to r$ does *not* denote a "gives", but is a logical operator, with the following truth table:
$$\begin{array}{cc|c}
a & b & a\to b\\
\hline
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 1
\end{array}$$
That is, $a\to b$ is a logical statement that can be true or false. It basically says "$b$ is at least as true as $a$".

It is completely equivalent with $\sim a\lor b$.

Comment: So basically the rightmost column is true if the state of p q and r are consistent with the logic of the statement?

Comment: @user2651000: I think you could express it that way, yes.

Comment: I would say you simply misunderstood the question.  The table is evaluating a statment with three variables.  $S(p,q,r)$  and you are evaluating the truth values for the 8 possible states of $p,q,r$.  Think you misunderstood this as statement $S(p,q) = r$ and thought to evaluate the values of the statement with two variable for the 4 possible states of $p, q$.  But that is the wrong why of interpreting the question.

Answer (score 1):

I would say you simply misunderstood the question.  The table is evaluating a statment with three variables.  $S(p,q,r)$  and you are evaluating the truth values for the 8 possible states of $p,q,r$.  Think you misunderstood this as statement $S(p,q) = r$ and thought to evaluate the values of the statement with two variable for the 4 possible states of $p, q$.  But that is the wrong why of interpreting the question.

You are being asked to evaluate the truth of $S(p,q,r) = \lnot p \lor q \to r$

which is:

$$\begin{array}{ccc|c}
p&q & r & S=(\lnot p\lor q) \to r\\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 &0\\
0 & 0 & 1 &1\\
0 & 1 & 0& 0\\
0 & 1 & 1& 1\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 0& 0\\
1 & 1 & 1& 1\\
\end{array}$$

You interpreted it to mean to evaluat the truth of $R(p,q) = \lnot p \lor q$ which you evaluated as:

$$\begin{array}{cc|c}
p&q  & R=(\lnot p\lor q)\\
\hline
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 1\\
\end{array}$$

We can combine the two results to get a clearer truth table:

$$\begin{array}{cc|c|c|c}
p&q &R=\lnot p \lor q & r& S=(\lnot p\lor q) \to r=R\to r\\
\hline
0 & 0 & 1 &0&0\\
0 & 0 & 1 &1&1\\
0 & 1 & 1& 0&0\\
0 & 1 & 1& 1&1\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0&1\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1&1\\
1 & 1 & 1& 0&0\\
1 & 1 & 1& 1&1\\
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 1):

You're not using the online tool incorrectly; you're doing your own truth-table incorrectly.

The whole point of a truth-table is to explore *all* possible truth-assignments to the propositional variables involved. So, given that each of the three variables involved, $p$, $q$, and $r$ can take on the value of either $0$ or $1$, there are $2^3=8$ possible truth-assignments that the table needs to consider, i.e. your table needs $8$ rows, not $4$. The online tool has it exactly right.